# Get android project code from android app though cant find apk file

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

This question is fairy simple.Please dont downvote or close this question without warning me about the problems in the comments.I want to get my project code.But i dont have the apk file.All i have is the app installed on my android phone.Can anyone tell me how to go about this?Though i think it is impossible as then anyone can get the project code from any app installed on their device.

The main problem is that I have manually deleted all the apks in one go from the file manager.All I have left is the app installed and running.

Thanks for your time

Comment: get the apk, easiest way is to send the apk to other device using share it, then decompile the apk. But serious advice -> use project management tools like github in future

Comment: **Though i think it is impossible as then anyone can get the project code from any app installed on their device.** it is definitely possible, hence you are supposed to use pro guard to increase the security of the apk

Comment: @MohammedAtif That is not my problem.I do not have any apk.I have deleted all apks in my phone using my file manager

Comment: as i said, use shareit to retrieve apk. this is the easiest way i know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am answering my own question.

I have to install APK Extractor app from the Google Play Store.This app will create a copy of the APK of any app installed on your phone and store the copy in a location that can be accessed by you.